# Boolean operations in Android resource file

Tags: android, android-resources

Is there a way to perform boolean logic inside an Android resource file? I'd like to calculate a boolean layout property based on two values.

Comment: No, there is nothing like that

Comment: Boolean operations are not supported in xml. However it's possible to create different resource files with different boolean values for particular device configurations. Write more about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly do that, but try looking into a Android [Selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

With that you set different layout-option based on boolean values, which you can access programmatically. So use a selecter and calculated your boolean property and then correctly pass this information to the selector in order to display the correct layout.